# How do I get the query parameter from paramMap in Angular 5?

Tags: angular

How do I get the query parameter from paramMap in Angular 5?

This code doesn't work as I'm trying to assign the value to void.  I want to chain additional calls in the switchmap that rely on the id.

```
    this.route.paramMap
    .switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
        console.log(params.get('id'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your route looks like this

```
{path: 'foo/:fid', component: fooDetailsComponent}
```

then in your component

```
export class PopDetailsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
private subscription: Subscription;
constructor(private actRoute: ActivatedRoute){
this.subscription = this.actRoute.params.subscribe(
  (params: any) => {
    if (params.hasOwnProperty('fid') && params['fid'] != '') {
      this.fooId = params['fid'];
  });
}
ngOnDestroy() {
  if(this.subscription) {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, do I need to do anything with this.subscription? Is it basically a dummy parameter?  What should I declare it as?  Also, params is deprecated, I would prefer to use the newer paramMap

Comment: `this.subscription` is of type `Subscription`. It's used to unsubscribe subscriptions, which prevents memory leaks. You can write `this.subscription.unsubscribe()` inside the function `ngOnDestroy`.

Comment: @Robbie Mills I updated the answer. yes, you can use paramMap also.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's the way to go, although I'm getting a syntax errors on the last ')' in the subscribe call

Comment: coz it should be called inside constructor() or ngOnInit()